# How can I analytically solve the factorial problem n! = k

Tags: permutations, combinations, factorial, binomial-theorem

Myself and other colleagues of mine were asked to solve the problem

$$
n! = k
$$

This seems simple as we all divided into the question only for us to dive out at the same pace.

Now my questions are

1. Can this problem be solved?
2. If No, Why not?

Comment: Do you mean to ask how you can solve for $n$ for a given value of $k$?

Comment: This is the same as solving $\Gamma(n+1)=k$. There is a math overflow [post](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/12828/inverse-gamma-function) on the inverse gamma function.

Comment: Are you able to factor $k?$ That would be about the only sensible question I could see here, given a very large integer with very small prime factors, find, by hand, the specific $n$ that gives you the correct exponent for each prime factor of $k.$

Comment: You can use [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) for large $n$.